# USB GPS pretends its a serial port

Tags: c#, gps, usb, serial-port

I'm trying to get data out of a USB GPS device, PL-2303. USB to Serial Bridge Controller.

So I tried this.

```
sp = new SerialPort(portname, 9600, System.IO.Ports.Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
sp.Open();
while (sp.IsOpen)
{
string serialPortData = sp.ReadLine();
}
```

The connection is open - but no data is received.  Do you think its because I'm trying to connect to a USB device by opening a serial port?   Or do you think its because the GPS data isn't being received?

Comment: Hmm, shouldn't have have to call `sp.Open()` first before it is actually open?

Comment: You forgot to turn handshaking on.  Set the RtsEnable and DtrEnable properties to true.

Comment: Sorry I guess I omitted open from the text snippet but it was in the code...

Comment: @Hans: Why?  The NMEA standard specifies that handshaking should be off.

Comment: The generic USB port emulator driver they throw at these products can't be relied upon to know anything about a nautical standard.

Comment: @iterationx - copy/paste is the only way 'we' can answer questions.  if you don't post the (non)running code, it's tough to help you.

Comment: @Hans: The PL-2303 isn't a GPS.  It's a USB <-> RS-232 converter which needs to be configured to match the GPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have the wrong baud rate.  Try the [standard settings for NMEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NMEA_0183#Serial_configuration_.28data_link_layer.29).

Comment: yeah it was the wrong baud rate, 4800 working without handshaking, strangely the device driver said that it was 9600. :|